# Counting vowels in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I use this code to search and count vowels in the string,

```
a = "run forest, run";
a = a.split(" ");
var syl = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < a[i].length - 1; i2++) {
        if ('aouie'.search(a[i][i2]) > -1) {
            syl++;
        }
    }
}

alert(syl + " vowels")
```

Obviously it should alert up 4 vowels, but it returns 3.
What's wrong and how you can simplify it?

Comment: I'm not native English speaking, so I might be wrong, but isn't `y` sometimes considered a vowel as well?

Comment: Apparently `y` can be both an vowel and a consonant in English, depending on its use, which sounds like a tough nut to crack with a regular expression. More about it [here](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var syl = ("|"+a+"|").split(/[aeiou]/i).length-1;
```

The `|` ensures there are no edge cases, such as having a vowel at the start or end of the string.

Comment: Are the `|` really necessary? If there is a vowel at the beginning/end/both, then the first/last/both element in array will be an empty string, but `.length` will count it.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your code, your if condition needs no i2

```
if('aouie'.search(a[i]) > -1){
```

I wonder, why all that use of arrays and nested loops, the below `regex` could do it better,

```
var str = "run forest, run";
var matches = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
    var count = matches ? matches.length : 0;
    alert(count + " vowel(s)");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2QPN2/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
a = "run forest, run";

var syl = 0;

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if('aouie'.search(a[i]) > -1){ 
            syl++;
        }
}

alert(syl+" vowels")
```

First, the split is useless since you can already cycle through every character.

Second: you need to use `i<a.length`, this gets the last character in the string, too.

Comment: In addition to this possible solution, i think you were finding number of WORDS with vowels intead of number of vowels

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is

```
s.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .match to compare a string to a regular expression.  g is global which will run through the entire string.  i makes the string readable as upper and lower case.

```
function getVowels(str) {
      var m = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
      return m === null ? 0 : m.length;
    }
```