# count the vowels in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to get the count of the vowels on the string using reduce() method of javascript. The below is the code and the problem is that the value of a, e, i, o, u after the destructuring the acc is coming as undefined.

```
const str = 'I am just a string. I mean nothing serious and I am being used to count the number of vowels I have.';

const strArr = str.split('');



const mapVowels = strArr.reduce(countVowels, {});

function countVowels(acc, char) {
  console.log(char)
  var { a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0, u = 0 } = acc;
  if (char === "a") {
    return {...acc, a: a + 1};
  }
  if (char === 'i') {
    return { ...acc, i: i + 1}
  }
  if (char === 'e') {
    return { ...acc, e: e + 1}
  }
  if (char === 'o') {
    return { ...acc, o: o + 1}
  }
  if (char === 'u') {
    return { ...acc, u: u + 1}
  }
}
console.log(mapVowels)
```

I want mapVowels to be an object with keys a, e, i, o,u and value the number of time they are repeating in the str.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting vowels in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912935/counting-vowels-in-javascript)

Comment: @RandyCasburn Not really. The OP already has code, and the code has a very specific problem that needs to be solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ori has you covered on the reason your code doesn't work. You're also duplicating a lot of code, so here's a `reduce` example that allows you to build up the counts in one line.

```js
const str = 'I am just a string. I mean nothing serious and I am being used to count the number of vowels I have.';
const vowelRe = /[aeiou]/;

const countVowels = str.split('').reduce((acc, c) => {

  // Test if the current letter is a vowel
  const found = vowelRe.test(c);
 
  // If it is: if the vowel exists in the object as a key increase the count,
  // and if it doesn't set it to zero, and then increase the count
  if (found) acc[c] = (acc[c] || 0) + 1;

  // return the accumulator
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(countVowels);
```

Answer (score 5):

When a non vowel character is found, you don't return `acc`. So `acc` is `undefined` on the next iteration, and the destructuring fails. Return `acc` even if it's not a vowel:

```js
const str = 'I am just a string. I mean nothing serious and I am being used to count the number of vowels I have.';

const strArr = str.split('');

const mapVowels = strArr.reduce(countVowels, {});

function countVowels(acc, char) {
  var { a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0, u = 0 } = acc;
  
  if (char === "a") {
    return {...acc, a: a + 1};
  }
  if (char === 'i') {
    return { ...acc, i: i + 1}
  }
  if (char === 'e') {
    return { ...acc, e: e + 1}
  }
  if (char === 'o') {
    return { ...acc, o: o + 1}
  }
  if (char === 'u') {
    return { ...acc, u: u + 1}
  }
  
  return acc;
}
console.log(mapVowels)
```

In addition, you can make the code more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by creating an array or a string of vowels, and using [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) or [`Array.inclues()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to identify vowels:

```js
const vowels = 'aieou';

const str = 'I am just a string. I mean nothing serious and I am being used to count the number of vowels I have.';

const strArr = str.split('');

const mapVowels = strArr.reduce(countVowels, {});

function countVowels(acc, char) {
  if(!vowels.includes(char)) return acc;
  
  const { [char]: val = 0 } = acc;
  
  return {...acc, [char]: val + 1};
}

console.log(mapVowels)
```

Comment: You could make it even more optimized by using a `switch` statement on the `char` rather than `includes()`, but I agree this is probably more readable.

Comment: I was looking more for a DRY optimization then performance, but that's something to consider as well.

Comment: Great! Thank you Ori Drori. Great optimization!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
const str = 'I am just a string. I mean nothing serious and I am being used to count the number of vowels I have.';

const VOWELS = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'];

var count = str.trim().split('').reduce((accum, el) => {
  if (VOWELS.indexOf(el) > -1) {
    accum[el] += 1;
  }
  return accum;
}, {
  'a': 0,
  'e': 0,
  'i': 0,
  'o': 0,
  'u': 0,
  'y': 0
});

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach take the wanted characters, builds an object for counting and takes a check and count the character, if in the object.

```js
const
    vowels = 'aieou';
    str = 'I am just a string. I mean nothing serious and I am being used to count the number of vowels I have.';
    mapVowels = Array
        .from(str.toLowerCase())
        .reduce(
            (acc, char) => (char in acc && acc[char]++, acc),
            Object.assign(...Array.from(vowels, c => ({ [c]: 0 })))
        );

console.log(mapVowels);
```